# Does pumping lemma ever fail?

Tags: computer-science, automata, pumping-lemma

Consider the language F = {$a^i$$b^j$$c^k$ | i, j, k ≥ 0 and if i = 1 then j = k}.

1. Show that F is not regular.
2. Show that F acts like a regular
   language in the pumping lemma. In other words, give a pumping length
   p and demonstrate that F satisfies the three conditions of the
   pumping lemma for this value of p.
3. Explain why parts (a) and (b)
   do not contradict the pumping lemma

I tried to choose x=empty string,y=a and z=$b^p$$c^p$ to prove that a$b^p$$c^p$ is regular and it worked while the language is non-regular and it was supposed to fail with pumping lemma.What is the reason? Do I have to cut off the first non-repeating parts like *a*?

Comment: So you are asking about how to answer question 3?

Comment: Right,I don't know how to answer the question 3

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the solution and sharing it for others who have trouble with the same problem:
The pumping lemma is not violated because it states only that regular languages satisfy the three conditions, and it doesn’t state that nonregular languages fail to satisfy the three conditions.

Comment: In other words, the pumping lemma is an if-then statement, and the converse of a true if-then statement is not necessarily true.